# Jquery Fade in easy solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

How can i fadein a div after the submit in php? The action of the submit button is a action="" so it loads "again" the same page i have the following code after sending the email. In my css i have a display:none in .success

```
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) {   ?>
<script language=javascript">
    $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
  </script>

<div class="success">
  <p> Thanks</p> 
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks for the reply, should be a easy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a document.ready

```
<script language=javascript">
    $(function(){ 
        $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
     }); 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
   $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
});//DONE ^_^
```

Need to use the onload method of jQuery.